# PostgreSQL query I don't understand

Tags: postgresql

I'm sorry for my title, but it's totally right. I don't know PostgreSQL well, but I have to take over other person's application. I know SQL, so it's usually no problem to take over any application based on MSSQL, Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL, ... but here is some kind of PostgreSQL facet. Could anyone, please, explain this query to me?

```
select company_generate_course_template_fc
       ((select company_id from company order by 1 desc limit 1)::int)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query calls the  function `company_generate_course_template_fc()` passing the result of the query: `select company_id from company order by 1 desc limit 1` as an argument. The result is cast to an integer using `::int` ([see the manual for details](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS))

Apart from the `::int` part (and the different ways of limiting the result to a single row), this wouldn't be much different in other databases

The ANSI SQL equivalent of `::int` would be `cast(... as integer)`

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I was so stupid because of early morning :-[... When I've got another look at the query, I knew. Thank you again and I'm sorry for this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about ::int it's type casting from string (company_id) to integer value